# How to print the layers of the tensorflow 2 saved_model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am using tensorflow 2.6.2 and I downloaded the model from the [Tensorflow 2 Model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md)
I am able to load the model using this

```
import tensorflow as tf

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        model = tf.saved_model.load("/home/user/git/models_zoo/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/saved_model/")
```

But unfortunately I am not able to see all the layers of the model using the below

```
for v in model.trainable_variables:
  print(v.name)
```

which should ideally print all the layers in the network, but I am getting the following error

```
    print(model.trainable_variables)
AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'trainable_variables'
```

Can someone please tell, what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you look at [their example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb)? Under `Create model and restore weights for all but last layer` there is some code that looks very suspicious to what you want to achieve for loading. Under `Eager mode custom training loop` you will find the trainable variables...

Comment: @André, I couldn't find a code to load and print the layers in this example.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but as I see it, loading the weights is literally what is described in `Create model and restore weights for all but last layer`. When you're done with that, you can `print(detection_model.trainable_variables)`.

Comment: @André That's exactly what I have written above in the question I posted and it didn't work :D

Answer (score -1):

I was able to print using this

```
        loaded = tf.saved_model.load("/home/user/git/models_zoo/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/saved_model/")
        infer = loaded.signatures["serving_default"]
        for v in infer.trainable_variables:
            print(v.name)
```